# How can I find the replies and comments by an author in a thread?

Tags: support

In [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read),

> To search: Use the search box in the upper-right corner. To search the
>   answers of the current question, use inquestion:this. For example:
>
> inquestion:this "Code Complete"

If I want to find the replies and comments by a particular user, how can I find them? For example, `inquestion:this "Dave Clarke"` doesn't return anything, but the user indeed posted at least two replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are not designed to be searched in this way.  The focus of the site is on questions and answers, not comments.

You can see a user's comment history in their profile, abut it is not going to be searchable for specific keywords.

Comment: thanks. how to search for a user's replies in a thread?

Comment: @Tim If you mean their answers, there's a search criteria for answers.

Comment: what is the search criteria

Comment: @Tim http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 2):

If the post or comment you're looking for is posted before [the last time SEDE was updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859) you can use the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/538463?postid=1711&UserId=231469):

```sql
declare @postid int = ##postid:int##
declare @userid int = ##userid:int##

select c.id as [Comment Link]
     , c.postid as [Post Link]
from comments c
inner join posts p on p.id = c.postid
where ( p.id = @postid
or p.parentid = @postid)
and c.userid = @userid
union
select null
     , id
from posts p
where (p.id = @postid
or p.parentid = @postid)
and p.owneruserid = @userid
```

When run it will list all comments and posts (question and answers) where the user is the author of.